# Cannot compile code with gcc 4.6.1

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

This code below compiles fine with VS2010 but doesn't want to compile with gcc 4.6.1.:

```
#ifndef IS_CHAR_H_INCLUDED
#define IS_CHAR_H_INCLUDED
#include <type_traits>

template<class Int_T>
struct Is_Char_
{
    enum {value = false};
};

template<>
struct Is_Char_<char>
{
    enum {value = true};
};

template<>
struct Is_Char_<unsigned char>
{
    enum {value = true};
};

template<>
struct Is_Char_<signed char>
{
    enum {value = true};
};

template<class Int_T>
struct Is_Char : Is_Char_<typename std::remove_cv<Int_T>::type>
{

};

#endif // IS_CHAR_H_INCLUDED

#ifndef PROMOTE_H_INCLUDED
#define PROMOTE_H_INCLUDED
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/find.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/next.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/deref.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/end.hpp>
   //#include "Is_Char.h" doesn't have to be here this file is pasted above


/*Promotes Integer type to one up in size range*/
template<class Integer>
struct Promote
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<Integer>::value,"Non Integer type is not allowed.");
    /*Check correct type - depending on Integer being signed or unsigned*/
    typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_signed<Integer>::value,
                                boost::mpl::vector<signed char,short,int,long,long long>,
    boost::mpl::vector<unsigned char,unsigned short,unsigned int,long,long long>
                                     >::type types;
    /*
    Find this type from the list above - substituting Integer for signed or unsigned char iff Integer is of type char
    */
    typedef typename boost::mpl::find<types,
    typename std::conditional<Is_Char<Integer>::value,
    typename std::conditional<std::is_signed<Integer>::value,signed char,unsigned char>::type, Integer>::type>::type this_type;

    /*If Integer is int and if size of it is == to long promote int to long long (iterate to next element twice)*/
    typedef typename boost::mpl::eval_if<boost::mpl::bool_<((std::is_same<Integer,int>::value || std::is_same<Integer,unsigned int>::value)
                                                                && (sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)))>,
                                         boost::mpl::next<typename boost::mpl::next<this_type>::type>,
                                         boost::mpl::next<this_type>
                                        >::type next_type;
    /*Check if iterator points within range or if one pass end which means that Integer was u/long long*/
    typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_same<typename boost::mpl::end<types>::type,next_type>::value,Integer,typename boost::mpl::deref<next_type>::type>::type type;
};

#endif // PROMOTE_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Add the error message please.

Comment: What error is reported by gcc?

Comment: Can you include the errors you get from the compiler?

Comment: @Patrick Douglas && Ciaran the interesting thing here is that errors are not listed - the only line indicating that there are errors is ||=== Build finished: 59 errors, 152 warnings (0 minutes, 40 seconds) ===|. I think that it would be best if you try to compile it for yourself and the you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't using some build utility or makefile that is hiding the error messages?

Comment: @JimClay I'm sure, try it for yourself.

Comment: The -1 is because you didn't ask a question and you have given no indication that you've put any effort into your problem at all. Show how you attempted to compile it. Show some of the error messages (starting with the first one). Show where in the code the first error occurs.

Comment: So how exactly are you building the code? You can't be calling `g++` directly, or you'd see the error messages. Are you using `make`? Or an IDE? Or something else? We can't help you unless you show the error message - as far as I (and my compiler) can see, this code is fine.

Comment: @Rob there are no error msgs displayed. I've spent last four days trying to do it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I'm using code::blocks, in toolchain I've specified g++ as a compiler mingw32-g++

Comment: If you don't see error messages, then you're not looking hard enough. They exist somewhere. Run your compiler on the command line if you must. But first, look at the "Build messages" tab.

Comment: @rob here is the log from attempted build of this file: http://pastebin.com/DW3T5D8F find any errors listed.

Comment: Since you have `-Wfatal-errors` set, everything listed there is an error.

Comment: @RobKennedy: that option just makes the compiler stop after the first error. Most of the warnings are still just warnings, but `-Wpedantic-errors` turns some of the less useful warnings into errors.

Comment: Ah, you're right, @Mike. I was thinking of `-Werror`, but that one isn't present in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>My guess is that you're not specifying `--std=c++0x` when compiling, so C++11 features such as `std::is_integral<>` aren't available. Your code compiles for me when I use that option.</strike>

UPDATE: now that you've shown the compiler output, the problem is that you've enabled just about every possible warning, and also set `-Wpedantic-errors` to treat some of them as errors. Many of these warnings are triggered by perfectly sensible code, and most authors (including Boost) won't have taken the time to fix or work around all of them.

You should certainly remove `-Wpedantic-errors`, unless you have a particular requirement that no code should ever use compiler-specific extensions; in that case, you probably can't use Boost. It would probably be a good idea to disable some of the less useful warnings too - you can't fix the ones that Boost generates, so all they do is make it harder to spot genuine warnings about your code. I generally aim to compile cleanly with `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: Yes. My command was `g++-4.6.1 -c test.cpp --std=c++0x`, and it compiled with no errors.

Comment: without specifying boost directories?

Comment: They're in my default include path.

Comment: when I've tried compile with what you've shown I'm getting error from gcc telling unrecognized option -4.6.1

Comment: I have several different versions installed, with different names. Try `g++ -c test.cpp --std=c++0x`

Comment: how is it possible that this same compiler compiles this code and doesn't? I've tried gcc 4.6 and yes this code compiles fine with it, but not with gcc 4.6.1

Comment: how can I add boost libraries to default include path?

Comment: It's `-std=c++0x`: one dash, not two, but I guess that's what both of you used, otherwise the compiler driver would complain about an unrecognized option...

Comment: @Mike Seymour Hey Mike, it works now! Indeed doing just with -Wall and -Wextra seems to do the trick. I is bit surprising though, for I've expected boost to be std conformant in every inch. Anyway, big thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is not in your code. The problem is that you can't find the compiler's error messages. Fix that problem before you do anything else!

Comment: There were 59 errors. So somewhere there are 59 error messages. You have to find out where.

Comment: and I'm telling you that there are none listed! How hard it is to understand what I'm telling you?!

Answer (score 0):

Run the exact `g++` command inside a terminal. You'll see the errors then. Don't use an IDE for that.